# Proving an Inequality in the $L^1$-Norm by Density of $C^{\infty}_{0}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

**Problem**

We wish to prove the following limit:

For all $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$:

$t^{n(1-1/p)} ||(P_{t} \ast f)(x) - P_t (x) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) \text{d}y ||_{L^p_x(\mathbb{R}^n)} \rightarrow 0 $, as $t \rightarrow \infty$,

where $P_t$ is the poisson kernel: $P_t(x) = t^{-n}P(t^{-1}x) = t^{-n} \displaystyle \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\pi^{\frac{n+1}{2}} (1+|t^{-1}x|^2)^{\frac{n+1}{2}} } $, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $t>0$.

**Proof**

We start by assuming $f \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, with $R>0$ such that:

supp$f \subseteq \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ |x| \leq R \}$.

Then $t^{n(1-1/p)} ||(P_{t} \ast f)(x) - P_t (x) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) \text{d}y ||_{L^p_x(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C t^{n(1-1/p)} ||t^{-n} \nabla P(t^{-1}x)||_{L^p_x(\mathbb{R}^n)} \int_{y \leq R} \frac{|y|}{t} f(y) \text{d}y $

$ \leq C t^{-1} R ||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} \rightarrow 0 $, as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

So we have shown that the statement holds for $f$ smooth with compact support. The next part is the part I don't understand.

For $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n) $, we use the fact that $ C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and use the following inequality which is proven earlier:

$ t^{n(1-1/p)} ||(P_{t} \ast f)(x) - P_t (x) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) \text{d}y ||_{L^p_x(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C||f||_{L^1} $.

According to the paper I am reading, this is enough to get the desired convergence, by a density argument.

In other words, we should let $\{ f_k \} \subseteq C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $f_k \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then we know that the above inequality and convergence hold for each $f_k$, and we should be able to use convergence of $f_k$ into $f$ to get the final result.

I am struggling to see exactly how we can do this. If someone could please provide a hint/first step, that would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very standard argument. Say $\text{LHS}(f)$ is the stuff on the left side.

Say $f\in L^1$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $g$ smooth with $$||f-g||_1<\epsilon/2.$$

$\newcommand\LHS[1]{\text{LHS}#1}$Choose $T$ so $$\LHS(g)\le\epsilon/2\quad(t>T).$$If $t>T$ then $$\LHS (f)\le\LHS (g)+\LHS(f-g)<\epsilon.$$

**Exercise:** Explain how this result is really just a special case of the fact that a uniform limit of continuous functions (on $[0,\infty]$) is continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will work on that exercise too!